# Suggested pattern to use for import procedure?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Here is the scenario.
You have different file formats containing the same data. You can decide programmatically to skip the interpretation of some data or to use different algorithms.

For instance: you are importing a file with some geometric entities like lines, circles, and texts. You can import the texts as names for a group of geometric entities. Or, in another schema, the texts represent generic data (order no., customer name). In another configuration, you skip them all.

That's what I think.
Each step is represented by a service.
Each service produces part of the result and can handle only specific pieces of data.
Each interpreted data must be marked as "interpreted", so further services will not try to interpret it again.
All these services are invoked programmatically in a specific order depending on the configuration.
They cannot run async.

I'm thinking about the "Pipes and Filters Pattern".
But also the "Saga Pattern" in the orchestration variant.
My main goal is to have good readability about the import sequence and the ability to add, remove, and replace very easily each steps in different patterns.

Thank you.

Comment: if you know what services should handle and order of executing, I think [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) is way to go

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is a perfect example to implement the Factory Method design pattern and I hope that the following structure will help you to understand how it will be implemented as well.
[image]

Okay, so what is happening there, a Dialog can get object created with implementation or process of object creation hidden inside the **WindowsDialog** or the **HtmlDialog** so this somehow matches the various document type problem, so you can write those functions to perform certain actions for each document type  and do your work further.